# SKTileMapNode tileRowIndex always returns 0 for a negative value outside its bounds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```swift
let tileRow = self.tileMap.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: point)
```

Let's say the `tileMap` has 20 rows, 20 columns, each 100x100. If `point` is a positive value greater than `tileMap`'s bounds, it will return 20 (counting from 0, so the index is for the next row that does not exist). If `point` is a negative value with its absolute value greater than `tileMap`'s bounds, it will return 0, so the first row that actually exists. This is a problem for verifying if the player moves outside `tileMap`'s bounds, because it will keep going down, as the function will always return 0 for the previous case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, to check one point out of the bouns on **SKTileMapNode**, you can use:

`self.tileMap.contains(pos)`

[image]

In this example, you can add points by clicking and they change color depending on whether they are inside or outside the map:
https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/TileMapExamples/TileMapExamples/GameScene.swift

Comment: Thank you! That's a good approach. However, is the behavior described in the question intended or not?

Comment: I think the goal do you want to reach (check if the player it's out of bouns) can't be solved with tileRowIndex. Right?

Comment: Yea, but I mean why a greater value would return the next index and a lower one would still return 0?

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui tileRowIndex and tileColumnIndex working for me. Please take a look at example I updated. https://imgur.com/a/Jxize7M